# NTP not syncing automatically with my internal NTP server

Tags: linux, centos, ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

I installed ntp on a centos server.

I modified `/etc/ntp.conf` replacing the default server entries with one entry to my internal NTP server's IP (1.2.3.4 is the IP of the NTP server):

```
server 1.2.3.4 iburst
```

When  I reboot the server and run ntpstat I see this:

```
unsynchronised
   polling server every 64 s
```

Then I run `sudo ntpdate 1.2.3.4` and see this message:

```
1 Dec 19:22:35 ntpdate[2339]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

Then I stop the service (`systemctl stop ntpd`) and run `sudo ntpdate 1.2.3.4` again to see it sync successfully:

```
1 Dec 19:25:11 ntpdate[2351]: adjust time server 1.2.3.4 offset 0.005316 sec
```

Now when I start the service back up and run ntpstat I see this message:

```
synchronised to NTP server (1.2.3.4) at stratum 4
   time correct to within 8065 ms
   polling server every 64 s
```

If I reboot now and run ntpstat it will say unsynchronized.
What am I doing wrong? It should be automatically syncing to the IP of the NTP server I put in the config file right?

Comment: how far off is it if you reboot again? as far as i can see, after running `ntpdate` and restarting ntpd, everything is fine - ntp makes small adjustments on its own after being 'roughed in'

Comment: Wrong time zone on the client, out by too much for the version of ntpd running on it? Not saving time to BIOS on reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just being impatient. After a reboot if I wait about 6 minutes and ran ntpstat it will show it is synchronized.

The polling interval says 64 s which I assumed meant it polls every 64 s, but it looks like it doesn't work like that exactly.

Comment: Also, while the NTPD is running and you want to manually sync the time, you need to run this command instead so that it uses a different port (because the daemon is already using it):

sudo ntpdate -u 1.2.3.4